# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in class

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I see this error when running the below code:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I can't find the reason.

```
 #ifndef DQMCBASE__H
 #define DQMCBASE__H
 const double pi=3.141592645;
 #define rnd() ((double)rand())/ RAND_MAX

 /**
  * The basic walker class. This class serves the purpose of providing 
  * a structure that can be reused by inheriting. 
  */
 class DQMCWalker {
   double _x;        ///&lt; dummy variable to implement basic 1D      Harmonioscillator      example.
  This variable will be removed in future versions.
   double _timeStep; ///&lt; is the timestep in between to simultanious simulations
 public:
   DQMCWalker();
   ~DQMCWalker();
   /**
    * implements a normal distribution that can be used for the walking 
    * process defined in 
    * @see WalkNormal()
    *
    * @param variance the variance of the distribution.
    * @param meanvalue the mean value of the distribution.
    *
    * @return A double distributed according to a normal distribution.
    */
   double NormalDistribution(double variance, double meanvalue);

   /** 
    * a virtual function that describes the walking process of the walker. 
    *
    * @return returns 0, always.
    */
   virtual int WalkNormal();
   virtual double Potential();
   virtual double Weight(double);
   int Copy(DQMCWalker);
   double SetDeltaT(double);
   double GetDeltaT();
 };


 /*  *
  * The simulation class is a basic class that implements the basic features of           walking, branching 
  * TODO
  */
 template <class walker>
 class DQMCSimulation {
   walker* _walkers;
   walker* _copies;
   double _refE;
   double _timeStep;
   int _population;
   int _max_walkers;
   int _last_pop,_cur_pop,_nCopies;
 public:

   /**
    * The constructor is used to define the simulation parameters of an instance. It      takes two parameters, 
    * namely, the number of walkers and the time step in between two iterations.
    * 
    * @param n the number of walkers used in the simulation.
    * @param dt the time step in between two iterations.
    */
   DQMCSimulation(int n, double dt);
   ~DQMCSimulation();

   /**
    * This function is used to perform one iteration. Every time this function is           called 
    * a walkers are move according to the implementation of DQMCWalker::Walk(), next    the 
    * reference energy is calculted according to the formula
    *  TODO
    * and lastly, a birth-death process is performed.
    */
   int Iterate();
   double GetReferenceEnergy();
   walker* WalkerArray();
 };

 #endif
```

up to here can be embeded into DQMCBase.h file

```
 /* DQMCBase.cpp */
 #include <iostream>
 #include<math.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<ctime>
 //#include <DQMCBase.h>
 using namespace std;


 DQMCWalker::DQMCWalker() {
   _timeStep=0.1;
   _x=0.0;
 }
 DQMCWalker::~DQMCWalker() {
   _x=0.0;
 }
 double DQMCWalker::NormalDistribution(double variance=1.0, double meanvalue=0.0) {
   int samples=12;
   double res = 0.0;
   for(int i=0;i<samples;i++)
     res +=rnd();
   res = (res - samples*0.5)*sqrt(variance)+meanvalue;
   return res;
 }
 int DQMCWalker::WalkNormal() {
   _x+=NormalDistribution(1.0,0.0)*sqrt(_timeStep);
   return 0;
 }
 double DQMCWalker::Potential() {
   return 0.5*_x*_x;
 }

 double DQMCWalker::Weight(double refE) {
   return exp(-(Potential()-refE)*_timeStep);
 }
 int DQMCWalker::Copy(DQMCWalker w) {
   _x = w._x;
   return 0;
 }

 double DQMCWalker::SetDeltaT(double timeStep) {
   return (_timeStep = timeStep);
 }

 double DQMCWalker::GetDeltaT() {
   return _timeStep;
 }

 template <class walker>
 DQMCSimulation<walker>::DQMCSimulation(int n, double dt) {
   _max_walkers = n;
   _timeStep = dt;
   _population = n;
   _last_pop = _cur_pop = _population;
   _walkers = new walker[2*n];
   _copies = new walker[2*n];
   for(int i=0;i<2*n; i++) {
     _walkers[i].SetDeltaT(dt);
     _copies[i].SetDeltaT(dt);
   }
 }

 template<class walker>
 DQMCSimulation<walker>::~DQMCSimulation() {
   delete[] _walkers;
 }


 template <class walker>
 int DQMCSimulation <walker>::Iterate() {
   int i;
   /* Make the walkers walk */
   for(i=0;i<_cur_pop;i++) 
     _walkers[i].WalkNormal();

   /* Calculating the reference energy */
   double avg=0.0;
   for(i=0;i<_cur_pop;i++) 
     avg += _walkers[i].Potential();
   avg/=_cur_pop;
   _refE =avg - (_cur_pop-_population)/(_population*_timeStep);
   _last_pop = _cur_pop;

   /* This is the part where walkers spawn and die */   
   int m,j;
   _nCopies = 0;
   for(i=0;i<_cur_pop;i++) {
     m = floor(_walkers[i].Weight(_refE)+rnd());
     if(m<3) m=3;
     if(m==0) { /* The poor Walker dies */
       if(_cur_pop>1) {
         _walkers[i].Copy(_walkers[_cur_pop]);
         i--, _cur_pop--;
       } else {
         cout << "WARNING :: Your population is dying!" << endl;
       }
     } else {
       for(j=1;j<m;j++) {
         _copies[_nCopies].Copy(_walkers[i]);
         _nCopies++;
       }
     }    
   }
   /* Adding the copies */
   for(j=0;j<_nCopies; j++) {
     _walkers[_cur_pop].Copy(_copies[j]);
     _cur_pop++;
   }


   return 0;
 }


 template<class walker>
 double  DQMCSimulation<walker>::GetReferenceEnergy() {
   return _refE;
 }

 template<class walker>
 walker* DQMCSimulation<walker>::WalkerArray() {
   return _walkers;
 }

 /*************************
  * 1D Harmonic Oscillator
 ************************/
 class DQMCHarmonic1DWalker : public DQMCWalker {
   double _x;
  public:
   DQMCHarmonic1DWalker() {
     _x=0.0;
   }
   int WalkNormal() {
     double dt = sqrt(GetDeltaT());
     _x+=NormalDistribution(1.0,0.0)*dt;
     return 0;
   }
   double Potential() {
     return 0.5*(_x*_x);
   }

   int Copy(DQMCHarmonic1DWalker w) {
      _x = w._x;
     return 0;
   }

 };
```

this is the main of the program

```
 int main() {
   srand ( time(NULL) );

   int i,j, count;
   double refE;
   cout << "Hamonic 1D:" << endl;
   DQMCSimulation<DQMCHarmonic1DWalker> simulation1(500,0.1);
   refE = 0.0;
   for(i=1; i<1000; i++) {
     simulation1.Iterate();
     refE += simulation1.GetReferenceEnergy();
     if(i%50==0) 
       cout << refE/i << ", ";
   }
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Try running a debugger to isolate what part of the code that triggers the segfault.

Comment: I strongly advise you to define all the classes in the header files instead of cpp

Comment: @fatih_k Only define those classes in header files which are meant to be used by other code. Classes which serve only as implementation detail are best hidden from the implementation and defined within an anonymous namespace in their .cpp file, thus even avoiding them to be exported.

Comment: @Walter, ofcourse implementation details should be hidden but they can be hidden from API headers while defining all classes in internal headers and this increses the eligibility of the code

Answer (score 0):

The first and easily noticeable problem is that You need to follow the **[Rule of Three/Five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)** for `DQMCSimulation` class.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but I could not find what should I do.please show me what should I do. thanks.